# Como validar sessão com AngularJS e PHP?

Tags: php, angularjs

Depois que o login for feito, como posso fazer a validação do usuário quando o mesmo passa de uma página para outra, dentro do sistema, usando AngularJS e PHP? Pois, quando trabalhei, apenas com html e php eu fazia da seguinte forma:

```
<?php
session_start();
$id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];
$usuario = $_SESSION['user'];

if ($usuario == ""){
   header("Location:index.php");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assumindo que você está consumindo algo em ajax aos moldes de uma API por exemplo, após fazer login, qualquer página em ajax que você quiser acessar no servidor deve ter algum tipo de verificação se o usuário está logado.

#### Passo 1

Na sua página de `login` você ativa uma variável de sessão chamada `$_SESSION['usuarioLogado'] = 1;` por exemplo.

#### Passo 2

TODA página retornada ao usuário deve conter um verificador, que pode ser um include com o seguinte código:

```
<?php
if($_SESSION['usuarioLogado'] != 1){
    $status = array('logado' => 0);
    echo json_encode($status);
    exit();
}
?>
```

#### Passo 3

No seu script angular você precisa, antes de usar o retorno do servidor, verificar se ele não contém a variável `logado` com valor de `0`, e caso tenha, abortar a operação atual e encaminhar o usuário para a tela de login novamente.

```
$http.get("arquivo-com-valores.php").success(function(data){
    $scope.retorno = data;

    //verifica se está logado
    if(angular.isDefined($scope.retorno.logado) && $scope.retorno.logado == 0){
        alert('Não está logado');
        document.location.href = "login.html";
    }

    //Continua com seu código normalmente...

});
```

Com isso vai esclarecer bem suas dúvidas, ai é só ir melhorando o código para se adaptar a sua realidade.

Comment: Vou tentar.
Tenho que criar o login com angular tb.

Comment: Tanto faz dos dois jeitos funciona. O importante e é registrar a sessao

Comment: Não, eu estava afirmando que ainda tenho que criar o parte que faz o login no sistema.